# How to replace last 5 digits of afield with '99999' using update query?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have one column. In that column all rows are having 10 digits i.e. `1234567890`. By using `PostgreSQL` update query, I need to update last 5 digits to 99999. i.e. `1234599999`

Can any one provide me update query for above requirement.

Comment: Hi, you may have noticed this Question getting negative ratings. This is because the way you've worded it doesn't show any effort that you've made to solve the problem, or details as to why you're stuck. You'll get a more positive reaction if you can show that you've done a bit of research, and aren't just trying to get strangers to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Integer divide your number by 100,000 (i.e. discard the remainder), multiply it by 100,000 then add 99,999:

`UPDATE table SET field = FLOOR(field / 100000) * 100000 + 99999;`

Comment: Indeed, but it is what you'd base the query on. And supplying a query is difficult given we don't know the database table name, the field names, and the field types.

Comment: I am new to PostgreSQL ,please provide me update sql.

Comment: `UPDATE your_table SET your_field = your_field / 10000 * 10000 + 9999;`

Comment: give me sample update query with your above logic based on that i can work --Fitzwillian

Comment: Use `floor` instead of `round`: `UPDATE your_table SET your_field = FLOOR( your_field / 10000 ) * 10000 + 9999;`

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy I don't mind it at all! The reason I wrote it as a comment on your answer, instead of writing my own or edit yours, was for you to make your answer better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table name SET column name = column name:: int / 10000 * 10000 + 9999 WHERE column name!=''''
```

Here column name having `varchar` data type I converted to int as per my requirement.